# How to order knockout bindings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js. I am stuck in a little bit strange situation ( its hard to explain but i am trying, sorry if i am not clear ). I am using custom binding and options binding on a single select-list :

```
  <select data-bind="options : arrayOfOptions, optionsText: 'Name', 
           optionsValue: 'Name', chosen: { }">
  </select>

ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingAccessor, 
                    viewModel, bindigContext) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor() || {});
        $(element).chosen(options);
    }
};
```

Here at runtime selectlist will fill with all available options from the `arrayOfOptions` array and `chosen` is a custom binding in which i am applying a [CHOSEN PLUGIN](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) on the select-list.

Now the problem i am facing here is that in custom binding when i applied choose plugin on select list at that time the selectlist is not filled with the options from the `arrayOfOptions` array. Means in a simple term the `custom binding` is executing before `options binding`. Can anybody please give me a solution for this so that custom binding applied after options binding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your call to `chosen` into the update.

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/avSfa/28/

--

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();

        var options = {default: 'Select one...'};
        $.extend(options, allBindings.chosen)

        $(element).attr('data-placeholder', options.default);                
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(element).chosen();
    }
};
```

--

Alternatively, you can use `setTimeout` to move the call to `chosen` to the bottom of the execution queue.  This will give the Knockout options binding time to do its work before `chosen` tries to transform it.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingAccessor, 
                    viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor() || {});
        setTimeout(function() { $(element).chosen(options); }, 0);
    }
};
```

Comment: In the 2nd example, the options will be set to an empty object before the setTimeout is called (and will remain empty). It needs to be assigned when the setTimeout is triggered.

Answer (score 10):

Create an after property with an array of bindingHandler names which this binding depends on.

`ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingAccessor, 
                    viewModel, bindigContext) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor() || {});
        $(element).chosen(options);
    },
    after:['options']
};`

Comment: @user1740381 does this not fulfill exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: I actually thought this would work, but i cannot manage to get this to work at all. after:['options'] doesnt seem to work... what is in the after array? It is also not mentioned in the documentation as far as i can see...

Comment: Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uaLxdrk/). `['options']` is a list of bindingHandler names, and it will check if the current data-bind contains any of those and it will defer until after those   have been bound. And you are correct, it's not in the docs, I found it in the source code.

Comment: It's used on the [value binding](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/value.js#L2).

Answer (score 1):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().options;

    options.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        $(element).chosen();
        $(element).trigger("chosen:updated");
    });

    var value = allBindingsAccessor().value;
    value.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        $(element).trigger("chosen:updated");
    });
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    if (element.options.length > 0) {
        $(element).chosen();
        $(element).trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
}
```

};

This Worked for me with KO JS 3.0

Comment: +1, this led me to the solution for a similar problem, good pattern when you want your custom-binding to do something after some other  binding (but if you want it run once only, you can also destroy the subscriber).

Answer (score 0):

While the answers above may solve the problem that was presented, they seem to fall short on customizing your chosen drop down menu, such as disabling search by passing {'disable_search':true}.

I suggest the following modifications to allow passing chosen customization in your binding.

```
<select data-bind="options : arrayOfOptions, optionsText: 'Name', 
    optionsValue: 'Name', chosen: { 'disable_search': true }">
</select>

ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().options;
        var chosenOptions = allBindingsAccessor().chosen;

        options.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            $(element).chosen(chosenOptions);
            $(element).trigger("chosen:updated");
        });

        var value = allBindingsAccessor().value;
        value.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            $(element).trigger("chosen:updated");
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        if (element.options.length > 0) {
            var chosenOptions = allBindingsAccessor().chosen;
            $(element).chosen(chosenOptions);
            $(element).trigger("chosen:updated");
        }
    }
};
```